# Examples of four dimensional tensors satisfying the Bianchi identity

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Is there an example of a $(4, 0)$-tensor field $T(X, Y, Z, W)$ that has the following properties:

(1) $T(X, Y, Z, W) = -T(Y, X, Z, W)$

(2) $T(X, Y, Z, W) + T(Y, Z, X, W) + T(Z, X, Y, W) = 0$ and

(3) $T(X, Y, X, Y) = T(Y, X, Y, X)$,

but these properties do not imply that

(4) $T(X, Y, Z, W) = -T(X, Y, W, Z)$

I could not prove whether this holds. On the other hand, if (1), (2) and (4) hold then (3) is valid (this is easy to prove).

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean if (1), (2) and (4) is valid then (3) is valid? (1), (2) and (4) are satisfied by the curvature tensors on a Riemannian manyfold.

Comment: I could not prove that (3) is valid if (1), (2) and (4) are, that is way I think maybe there is a counterexample...but I could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(x,y,x,y) = -T(x,y,y,x)$ by (4)

$\phantom{T(x,y,x,y)}= T(y,x,y,x)$ by (1)

(3) is a consequence of (1) and (4), you don't need Bianchi  identities.

Edit

You can find counterexample in dimension 2: Let $V$ be a two dimensional vector space $(e_1,e_2)$ it's basis. Let also $K_{ij}(x,y) = T(e_i,e_j,x,y)$. From (1) we have $K_{11} K_{22}= 0$ and $K_{21} = -K_{12}$. From (3) you get $K_{12}(e_1,e_2) = - K_{12}(e2,e1)$, and no info on $K_{12}(e_1,e_1)$ and $K_{12}(e_2,e_2)$. Thus the matrix of $K_{12}$ is 
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ -b & d\end{array}\right)
$$
for some $a,b, d \in \mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, if you replace (3) with (4) you would get $a=d=0$.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I did not explain well. I need to prove that if (1), (2) and (3) are valid then (4) is valid, or find a counterexample.

Comment: I do not see where do you use Bianchi identity.

Comment: Bianchi identity is going to simplify to (1) since the dimension is only 2. It yields nontrivial conditions only when the dimension is at least 3

Comment: I think that the matrix of $K_{12}$ is with a and d equal in the beginning. But why a=0 gives a counterexample?

Comment: a=d =0 gives you standard Riemanninan curvature tensor. The counterexample is $a\neq 0$

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!